# How many times can a stormwarden's Blade Storm trigger?

Tags: dnd-4e, ranger

[Stormwarden](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/paragonpath.aspx?id=51):

> Blade Storm (11th level): As long as you are armed with a melee weapon and are capable of making an opportunity attack, one adjacent enemy (your choice) takes damage equal to your Dexterity modifier at the end of your turn.
>
> Twin-Blade Storm (16th level): As long as you are armed with a melee weapon and are capable of making an opportunity attack, two adjacent enemies (your choice) take lightning damage equal to your Dexterity modifier at the end of your turn.

These are different features and do not consume opportunity attacks (and in fact, cannot, as they occur on the player's turn.)

Does this mean that one adjacent enemy takes 2*Dex damage every round?

Comment: This says yes: http://community.wizards.com/wiki/Dnd:Char_op_-_QnA_compilation: If someone wants to work it up into a full fledged answer with argumentation? (I do dislike self-answers...)

Comment: I must admit, I don't understand the skill text at all.  What does "capable of making an opportunity attack" mean when its your turn? When will that condition not be met? Opportunity attacks can only happen when its not your turn.

Comment: @GMNoob. If a creature is [Dazed](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/glossary.aspx?id=133) or [Stunned](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/glossary.aspx?id=144) she cannot take immediate or opportunity actions (or no actions at all in the latter case). These conditions prevent the cited stormwarden features to deal automatic damage to adjacent creatures at the end of her turn.

Comment: @Brian I disliked self-answers at first too, but reading [this](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/) changed my mind.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

While similarly named and similar in feature and function, ***Blade Storm*** and ***Twin-Blade Storm*** are different features.

Since ***Twin-Blade Storm*** does not say something along the lines of "your Blade Storm now affects two adjacent enemies" we must assume that they are separate effects.

So:

Your turn ends and you and three of your enemies meet the required conditions.

You may damage one of them with ***Blade Storm***

You may damage two of them with ***Twin-Blade Storm***, one of whom may be the enemy damaged with ***Blade Storm***

Comment: +1 There are a lot of places where features are phrased like this, and I assume it's intentional, because there are plenty of other places where features are phrased the other way ("feature X now does Y").

Answer (score 1):

Hmmm... well the normal thing is that same source cannot trigger twice at the same time.  But in this case, it doesen't say it upgrades the previous one.  But looking at it now, 1 says its regular damage and 1 says its lightning damage.  So from that logic, yes, its possible that you can have one adjacent enemy take the dex modifier damage twice, but the first dex damage would be normal while the second dex modifier would be lightning damage (thus, if there is resistance to lightning, they may take reduction or no damage at all for that part).